# How to refer remote hadoop jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

how to add hadoop jar file avail in another computer(Ubuntu) using teamviewer, to run java program in windows eclipse.

Comment: You need to get the jar via ftp and add it to your eclipse project.

Comment: Thank..I will try...

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer doesn't affect your Java classpath.

Download the hadoop jar file and add it as a library to Eclipse.  Or, better, use Maven/Gradle rather than messing with JAR files yourself.

Ubuntu / Windows doesn't matter. Java is cross platform